# Detect any sound activity in windows via CMD

Tags: windows-10, command-line, audio, cmd.exe

**Hello**,
I wanna ask if there any tool or command that let you listen to your speakers in windows and do a task or run another script when a sound is detected ?

**THANKS**.

Answer (score 0):

The program that come to my mind is Process Monitor. I use it to detect the app which is making background sounds in Windows.
https://www.itechtics.com/identify-programs-making-sound-windows/#Find_the_program_making_sounds_using_Process_Monitor

Comment: But I need a program that supports command line interraction .